# How can I select all my column rows with the sum(column)

Tags: sql, sum

```
select p_id,paid_amount,date, from payments
```

that's my query and it works fine, but when i add the sum column it selects just the first row.

```
select p_id,paid_amount,date,sum(paid_amount) as 'sum' from payments
```

Comment: and when i group by p_id    like                                                              select p_id,paid_amount,date,sum(paid_amount) as 'sum' from payments GROUP by p_id      the paid_amount and the sum will be exactly alike

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: The second query is invalid SQL and won't run. Which database product are you using?

Comment: What's your DBMS? When it supports Windowed Aggregates it's simple: `sum(paid_amount) over ()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make two queries.

```
SELECT p_id,paid_amount,date, FROM payments;
SELECT SUM(paid_amount) FROM payments;
```

Answer (score 1):

Most DBMSes support Windowed Aggregates, then it's a simple

```
select p_id,paid_amount,date,
  sum(paid_amount) over () as "sum" 
from payments
```

Otherwise you can use a Scalar Subquery:

```
select p_id,paid_amount,date,
  (select sum(paid_amount) from payments) as "sum"
from payments
```